# Finding the closure of each of the following subsets of Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

(1){$(x,y):x^2+y^2<1,x,y\in \mathbb R$}.

(2){$(x,y):\frac{1}{y}\in \mathbb Z^+,x\in \mathbb R$}.

(3){$(x,y):x>0,y\in \mathbb R$}.

All i know that closure is the smallest closed set containing the original set.From this,the closure of (1) seems to be a circular disk centered at origin and of radius 1.Closure of (3) is right half plane.But,not sure about (2).

Also,help me writing these arguments analytically.

Comment: Well, what does closed *mean*.  It means it contains all it's limit points.  Some limit points of $goo < foo$ are $goo = foo$. That's why our intuition of "closing up that fuzzy endpoint" to make a closed set work.  So for number two, what are the limit points of (x,1/n)?  Hint: what is the limit of 1/n?

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you just need to take the union of the set with

$A=\{(x,0)|x \in R \}$

Note that the complement of the new set is open. Therefore the union is closed, as expected.

Any point $a\in A$ is a limit point of the original set. Because any open sphere around $a$ contains an element of the original set. So, all we need to do is to include the limit points in the set.

Answer (score 0):

If you like me, you went to high school and saw that $(a,b)$ has "open" end points and $[a,b]$ has "closed" end points and it kind of intutively makes sense that we can "close" an interval be "capping close" the endpoints.  Then you get to analysis and you have a very technical and abstract definition you don't feel comfortable with.  But you still figure a Set = {some condition < some other condition} can be closed by capping the "<" with "$\le $".

But what does it actually *mean*?

Well, a closed set is a set that contains all its limit points.  So the closure of a set is simple to take a set, find all the limit points that aren't in it... and put them in it.

For $(a,b)$ those "fuzzy endpoints" $a$ and $b$ are clearly limit points (because we get infinitely close to them while still staying in our set) so the closure of $(a,b)$ is to take $(a,b)$ and add $a,b$.

[Okay, that's being really *informal* about limit points.  Reread your text's definition. Note, $a,b$ are just the limit point that are outside the set.  All the points $(a,b)$ that are inside are also limit points but they are already inside.]

So 1) and 3)  The limit points that are not in the set...  A limit point, $p$ of $S$ is a point so that for every posible distance $r$, no matter how small there is a point $x$ of $S$ so that $d(p,x) < r$.  That means $p$ is "infinitely close" to the set (even though $p$ is not in $S$.

So if $p = (a,b)$ and $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and $ r > 0$ then... take $(a', b')=(a(1-.9r),b(1-.9r))$. $d((a,b),(a',b') = .9r < r$ and $a'^2 + b'^2 < a^2 + b^2 = 1$ so $(a',b')$.  So $(a',b')$  is in $S$.  So all $(x,y): x^2 + y^2 = 1$ are limit points of $S$ not in S.

So closure is $\{(x,y)| x^2 + y^2 < 1\} \cup \{(x,y)| x^2 + y^2 = 1\} = \{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 \le 1\}$.

[Okay, we *also* have to show if $x^2 + y^2 > 1$ then $(x,y)$ is *not* a limit point.  We do this by letting $r = 1 - (x^2 + y^2)$ and showing there are not point in $S$ within this range of $(x,y)$.  Because the distance from $(x,y)$ and $(0,0)$ is $1 + r$ and the distance from $(x,y)$ to any point in range is less than $r$ the distance fro $(0,0)$ to that point is more than 1.]

So that's basically how you do 1 and 3)

So how do you do 2).  Well, you have to find the limit points of  $S=\{(x,y):\frac{1}{y}\in \mathbb Z^+,x\in \mathbb R\}$.  It seems to me the text choose to be just slightly less than direct in the definition.  if $\frac 1y = n \in \mathbb Z^+ = \mathbb N$, then $y = \frac 1n$ so $S = \{(x,1/n)\}$.

What are the limit points of $S$?.  Well.... hint: we call them "limit points" because there are the limits of the points of the set.  Experience should tell us that $1.n \rightarrow 0$ but $1/n \ne 0$ for any $n$.

So "common sense" tells us the limit points are all $(x, 0)$.

And the technical definition of limit point bears this out.  Let $r > 0$ and let $0 < 1/n < r$ then for any point $(a,0)$ the point $(a,1/n)$ is within a distance of $r$ and is in $S$.  So $(a,0)$ is a limit point of $S$.

Likewise if $(a,b); b < 0$ then $(a,b)$ is *not* a limit point.  Because for $0 < r < |b|$ then all points $(x,y)$ in the range of $r$ will have $y < 0$ so $y \ne 1/n; n > 0$.

So the limit points of $S$ that are not in $S$ are $\{(x,0)\}$.  So the closure of $S$ is $S \cup \{(x,0)\}$.

[Oh, we need to also show that for $(x,y); y > 0; n \ne 1/n$ that $(x,y)$ is not a limit point.  That's because $1/(n-1) < y < 1/n$ for some $n$.  Take $r = \min (y - 1/(n-1), 1/n -y)$ and there will be no points of $S$ in that range.]